# Web interface for managing Tomcat services

Tags: web, tomcat, ansible

I have tons of tomcat servers, they are all in a virtual machine. At the moment there is a need to develop a web panel, where I can track the statuses of servers, change their configurations, stop and restart. Actually the question itself: with what technologies can I do this. Previously, there was an idea to use the playbook ansible.
How can I at least display the names of my servers on the page?

Answer (score 0):

There are two standard ways to monitor Tomcat:

- you can use Tomcat Manager, especially its [text interface](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Supported_Manager_Commands),
- you can use JMX directly or through the [JMX Proxy Servlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Using_the_JMX_Proxy_Servlet). On Tomcat's webpage you can find a [not so up-to-date list of MBeans](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Using_the_JMX_Proxy_Servlet). For some MBeans you'll have to fire up [jconsole](https://openjdk.java.net/tools/svc/jconsole/) and explore the names yourself.